# How to convert JavaScript function to work in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I write it like this, I can't use `this` keyword

```
  LoadDrawing(drawing_name) {
    this.glg.LoadWidgetFromURL(drawing_name, null, this.LoadCB,drawing_name);
  }


  LoadCB(drawing, drawing_name) {
    if (drawing == null) {
     return;
    }   
    this.DrawingName = drawing_name;
    drawing.SetParentElement("glg_area");
  }
```

I dont know what to pass that `drawing & drawing_name` get same thing when pass using params

```
LoadDrawing(drawing_name) {
        this.glg.LoadWidgetFromURL(drawing_name, null, this.LoadCB(param1,param2),drawing_name);
      }
```

Comment: Can you share the demo?

Comment: sorry I can't provide demo

Comment: Where is this `LoadWidgetFromURL` method coming from?

Comment: that is from JS library which is GLG

Comment: Well, not aware about glg but without demo I can't play the game of imagination! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve the this binding of `LoadCB` by defining it as an arrow function:

```
LoadDrawing(drawing_name) {
    this.glg.LoadWidgetFromURL(drawing_name, null, this.LoadCB,drawing_name);
}


LoadCB = (drawing, drawing_name) => {
    if (drawing == null) {
     return;
    }   
    this.DrawingName = drawing_name;
    drawing.SetParentElement("glg_area");
}
```

**Note that this is nothing to do with TypeScript, but ES6 JavaScript classes.**

ES6 class methods treat `this` bindings in the same way as a function defined using the `function` keyword does - in a way that is dependent on the call site rather than the lexical scope of the function. Arrow functions use lexical scope and so preserve the `this` binding in situations such as the above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this :

```
  LoadDrawing(drawing_name) {
        this.glg.LoadWidgetFromURL(drawing_name, null,(glg)=>this.LoadCB(glg,drawing_name),drawing_name);
      }    
      LoadCB(drawing, drawing_name) {
        if (drawing == null) {
         return;
        }   
        this.DrawingName = drawing_name;
        drawing.SetParentElement("glg_area");
      }
```